# What do ENR,TERM and APR mean in the HSI? Also how may I call this part on the HSI?

Tags: flight-instruments, gnss, attitude, g1000

How should I answer when my instructor asks me what it means during the flight? I searched but couldn't find a definitive answer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why can you not ask your instructor?  These are reasonable questions here, but even more so to ask the person you're paying to INSTRUCT you.

Comment: As a matter of fact, things are not going as well as you think in the flight schools in my country, Ralph. The student has to research and investigate and come ready to fly in every sense. Since my flight instructor gave me this question as an assignment and I could not find it after searching, I am writing the question here. I should also mention that I do not pay a fee because I am taking flight training with a 100% scholarship. If I am sharing my question here, I want you to know that I am sharing it because I want to get an answer...

Comment: ...I am an individual with the capacity to consider asking this question to the instructor.

Comment: -1 because I am confident the documentation on that instrument/display will describe the things it displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some information from the [FAA Learning Center Library](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/alc/libview_chapter.aspx?id=15239&chapter=Automation%20Management) that defines those terms used on a Garmin 1000 Horizontal Situation Indicator (HSI):

- CDI = Course Deviation Indicator;
- ENR = The  "ENR" annunciation tells you that a full-scale CDI deflection puts you at least **5 nm** from the desired course (when you are more than 30 nm from the destination airport); (**NOTE**: *On page 61 of this [Garmin G1000 manual](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/190-02177-00_A.pdf)  it shows "Automatic CDI Full-scale Deflection" at **2 nm** and **not at 5 nm** with the "ENR" annunciation. You should also read this manual carefully to ensure you have the most accurate information for your Garmin G1000).*
- TERM = The "TERM" annunciation tells you that a full-scale deflection puts you at least 1 nm from the desired course (when within 30 nm of the departure or destination airport);
- APR = The "APR" annunciation tells you that a full-scale CDI deflection puts you at least 0.3 nm from the desired course (when within 2 nm of the final approach fix).

**Excerpt from the FAA Learning Center Library linked document:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, sir.

Answer (score 1):

ENR, TERM and APR are required navigational performance for the phase of flight you are in.  It is used when navigating with GPS.

On a flight from Airport A (AAA) to Airport B (BBB).

The non-WAAS GPS receiver will start out in DPRT (departure) mode. This mode requires the GPS verify it knows its position with ±0.3 NM 95% of the time. The CDI will also show full scale deflection at 0.3 NM.

At a certain point the GPS will switch to TERM (terminal) mode.  This mode requires the GPS verify it knows its position with ±1 NM. The CDI will also show full scale deflection at 1 NM.

The GPS stays in TERM mode until passing more than 30 NM from AAA.  At this point, it will transition into ENR (enroute) or OCN (oceanic) mode.  This mode requires the GPS verify it knows its position with ±2 NM 95% of the time. The CDI will also show full scale deflection at 2 NM.

As the airplane flies within 30 NM from BBB.  The GPS will transition back into TERM mode.

When the approach is manually activated or automatically activated at the capture fix, the GPS will transition into APR (approach) mode.  The accuracy and sensitivity requirements are ±0.3 NM.

If the positional error exceeds the value above, the GPS will alert the pilot with another annunciator.  I am unsure what that is for a Garmin G1000 pictured above.

[image: Garmin Pilots Guide page 2-19]
[image: Garmin's Pilots Guide page 2-18]

Comment: Thank you so much, sir.

Answer (score 1):

The circled area in the bottom photo is called a "soft key". The button is a physical button, but the label ("CDI" in the example) is part of the display. Thus the buttons across the top, bottom, and sides of the display can have different functions depending on the context of what's displayed. As [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_key) notes, one also encounters softkeys like this in ATMs and self-service gas pumps.